# Linked server unaccessible after detach of unrelated database

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

We have 2 servers, `Server1` which is local and `Server2` which is the remote server.

On `Server1` there is a linked server configured for `Server2`.

On `Server1` there is a agent task which copies data from `Server2` to `Server1`.

This task did copy data to a DB called `DB1`. But this database was replaced by a new version which is called `DB2`. The task was rewritten to copy data to the new `DB2`.

One day the old `DB1` database wasn't needed anymore and we decided to detach it. After the detach the agent task now fails with the error `'Can't connect to Server(local)'`.

The agent task has no reference to the old `DB1`.
When I reattach `DB1` to the Server everything starts working again.

How can I detach `DB1` and still have the agent task working?

Comment: Change Catalog in [linked server definition](http://www.quackit.com/pix/sql_server/sql_server_2014/tutorial/linked_servers_2.png). Probably you still want to connect to `DB1` not `DB2`. After that release DB1 from duty ;)

Comment: This option is grayed out because we use the `Sql Server` Server type.

Comment: Script your linked server and share definition(mask vital data)

Comment: what's the user the agent is using to run the job? maybe that user has `DB1` as home database?

Comment: definition: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ba0157181cdf7e71b7bf#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: all our scripts have a `use DB2` as the first line of the tasks. I've checked again and there a no `DB1` references

Comment: if a user can't login because his database does not exists the `USE DB2` at the beginning of all your scripts will never execute because the user is not logged in. what's the user the agent is using to run the job? maybe that user has DB1 as default database?

Comment: the user has the master db as it's default database.